# VS Errors beginner

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, decompiling

I am new to the coding world and trying to learn. I am trying to understand how a .dll was written for what is it meant to do. I decompiled it and opened it as an assembly in VS. I learned a bit by looking at it's structure and I solved most of the errors that popped up when re-compiling it. But I am stuck at the very end. Here is the code:

```
public Request_NSBD FormRequest
{
    get =>this._request              
    private set
    {
        this._request = value;
    }     
}
```

I get errors CS1043, CS1513 and CS0161 in line 003 and errors CS1002 and CS1513 in line 004. Can anybody explain to me why I get this errors and how to fix them?
I checked online for CSxxxx and can't understand what is wrong. If I follow VS's advice the errors become more and "worse". I strongly appreciate any insight you may give me on this.

I am a mechanic and my way to learn things is to open them and see what is inside. I figured out it would be the same for code, perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you're compiling without C# 6 support.

Comment: Learning programming by decompiling the source of another program and trying to figure it out is probably not the best way to do it. Aside from probably getting into something that is overly complex for a beginner, its going to lead down a path of a lot of frustration trying to duplicate it without having a firm basis in the theory behind it.

Comment: @chris I don't believe you can copy/paste this code even in C# 6, it looks to be the compiler transformation of a read-only property with a lambda. I think the decompiler didn't get this one quite right.

Comment: @RonBeyer, Thanks, I wasn't quite sure whether expression bodies could be applied to `get`. Interesting that the decompiler would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a property to get/set a local variable `_request` of the type `Request_NSBD`. Try changing your code to this:

```
public Request_NSBDFormRequest
{
   get { return this._request; }
   set { this._request = value; }
}
```

As touched on by chris above, code written in certain styles take advantage of new language features, and may not compile with every version. Unless you are familiar with certain language syntax, it is best to use the more common implementation patterns.

Comment: Its not really valid code the way it has been decompiled, even in C#6. The decompiler here took some liberal license with the original code.

Comment: I would like to thank everybody for the care and help you provide to a total stranger, yet humble follower of this science. Gmiley code worked like charmed, solved issues and now dll is up and running. Thank a lot!

Comment: As was pointed out above in the comments of your question by @RonBeyer - this property was likely a read-only property. While it shouldn't make much difference to your sample code, learning to properly define your classes, properties, and methods/functions should be just as important as learning any other part of programming. Access modifiers are there to enforce proper usage of class functionality. If this property were a read-only, that would mean it is locked from being assigned to by anything that instantiates the class.

Answer (score 0):

To declare property, you have many way...

The old way (still usefull if you want to perform some check on your internal attribute):

```
public Request_NSBD FormRequest
{
    get { return _request; }
    private set { _request = value; }
}
```

New versions of C# allow you to declare your property like this :

```
public Request_NSBD FormRequest { get; private set; }
```

Now regarding the syntax you used, it's a mix of expression body and old way declaration.

If you want to write a readonly property, you would have written something like this :

```
public string MyString
{
    get
    {
        return "My string value";
    }
}
```

That is equivalent to this (with an expression body):

```
public string MyString => "My string value";
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to use any of c# 6 features, but a while back I read about the new auto property initialization: `public string Something { get; set; } = "Initial Value";`.